# Android : use of mediaStore with pdf file

Tags: android, download, mediastore

I try to use media store to store a pdf download (in Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) from a private network and to show it. I want the user to be able to choose the application to show it.
In my code, I have difficulty to define the file path "dataFile"
Can you give advice, thanks
Laurent

```
    String fileType="application/pdf";
    String filetxt="Choose pdf Application";
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .setDataAndType(dataFile, fileType);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,filetxt);
    context.startActivity(intentChooser);
```

Comment: First tell how you downloaded the file. You will have used an uri or have got one. Use that one. Use the mediastore uri.

Comment: `try to use media store to store a pdf download` Well be shure you solved that before you use ACTION_VIEW. Tell what you have already.

Answer (score 0):

`dataFile` should be `URI`, which can be easily created from `File` (or its path)

```
File file = new File(pathToFile);
Uri dataFile = Uri.parse(file.toString()); // or strightly pass pathToFile here
```

Comment: I use the DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS from mediaStore

Comment: `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(path, fileName);`

Comment: it's not mediaStore, the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated in API 29

Comment: so your directory is `MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, create your file URI using `ContentResolver` like in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#java)

Answer (score 0):

My solution after several tests :

```
   String[] projections = new String[]{
                    MediaStore.DownloadColumns._ID,
                };
   String selection =MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME+"=?";
   String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{newLocalpath};
   Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                        MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projections,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        null
                );
   Uri uri=null;
   int docIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.DownloadColumns._ID);
   if (cursor.moveToNext()==true) {
      uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getInt(docIndex));
   }
   if (uri!=null) {
      try {
         String fileType="application/pdf";
         String filetxt="Choose pdf Application";
         final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                .setDataAndType(uri, fileType);
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,filetxt);
         intentChooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intentChooser);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.d("application", "error starting download file: " + e.toString());
      }
```